# Addition of acid to 3-methyl-2,3-dihydropyran

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: structure of compound to which acid is added]

When a general acid, H-X reacts with the alkene in an addition reaction, which regiochemistry is expected?

In addition reactions X attaches to the most substituted carbon whilst H bonds to the carbon with fewest alkyl groups. In this case I would believe the **third** carbon to be the most substituted carbon due to it being bonded to three other carbons. And the **second** carbon to be where the hydrogen will bond. However, apparently it should be the other way around. And this would be the compound formed:

[image: product after addition of acid]

Why is the second carbon the most substituted in this case? Does it have to do with oxygen being more electronegative and thus it is seen as a higher prioritized substituent?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, you're using the Markovnikoff's rule here. Recall that it is only a *basic* rule intended for simple unsaturated hydrocarbons, and **fails** at more advanced examples involving heteroatoms or rings.

In this case, the first step is the addition of $\ce{H+}$ ion from the acid to the pi bond, which leads to the formation of a carbocation. The carbocation's positive charge is most stable next to the oxygen atom. Can you tell why?

In the second step, the $\ce{X-}$ ion will simply attach at the position where the positive charge was the most stable, leading to a product as you've shown in the second image.

Comment: Is the carbocation's positive charge more stable next to the oxygen because it has lone pairs which by resonance can donate a lone pair to form a new pi-bond (double bond) with X which is more stable than single bond?

Comment: @J.Se Yes, the donation of a _single_ lone pair from oxygen completes the empty octet of the positively charged carbon atom, thereby stabilizing the carbocation. Correct answer!